# ConnectionRefusedError when trying to connect to Gremlin Server using Python

Tags: python, gremlin

I am trying to use gremlin with python with gremlinpython package. I am getting the following error. Can anyone tell me how to solve this ? Any help is appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Yash/IdeaProjects/new/gremlin.py", line 10, in <module>
        g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g'))
      File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\driver_remote_connection.py", line 45, in __init__
        password=password)
      File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\client.py", line 76, in __init__
        self._fill_pool()
      File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\client.py", line 88, in _fill_pool
        conn = self._get_connection()
      File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\client.py", line 101, in _get_connection
        self._transport_factory, self._executor, self._pool)
      File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\connection.py", line 40, in __init__
        self.connect()
      File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\connection.py", line 46, in connect
        self._transport.connect(self._url)
      File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\tornado\transport.py", line 33, in connect
        lambda: websocket.websocket_connect(url))
      File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 458, in run_sync
        return future_cell[0].result()
      File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 10061] Unknown error
```

Comment: What code are you executing which is resulting in the error?

Comment: This is the code: 
1.from gremlin_python import statics
2.from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
3. from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
4. from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
5. from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
6. graph = Graph()
g = 7. graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g'))

Comment: The error states "connection refused", so are you sure Gremlin Server is running locally on 8182? If you believe that it is, can you connect to it with the Gremlin Console to verify? http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-via-console

Comment: I rephrased your question title to make it a bit more explicit and SEO friendly

Comment: Thank you @jbmusso, appreciate the help.

Comment: @stephen, I got it running, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

check your configration,set the host as ip not hostname

Comment: While this may help OP, it's better to add more details, explanation, examples, etc.  Please [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)